# Flutter: How to trigger Drawer's Item selection without pressing it

Tags: flutter, navigation, drawer

I am trying to create a Drawer widget in Flutter. The Drawer has 3 Drawer items - 3 screens (A, B, and C) and these items have been attached an _onSelectedItem() method to navigate to each screen. In A, I have a button, called buttonA. The question is how can I press the buttonA to navigate to the screen B? And at the same time select and hightlight the B drawer item? Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you can use a state manager to set the select and highlight condition to change whenever you want to navigate to a certain screen?

Comment: You mean using Provider or Bloc? @MohamadAssemNasser

Comment: Exactly. I believe Provider would be easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your help